# command `atq` demonstrate couple of tasks days ago

Tags: at

When I review the queue by command atq

```
$ atq
28  Wed Oct 31 10:23:00 2018
27  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
25  Tue Oct 30 21:19:00 2018
29  Wed Oct 31 10:42:00 2018
26  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
20  Tue Oct 30 18:25:00 2018
23  Tue Oct 30 18:28:00 2018
19  Tue Oct 30 15:43:00 2018
21  Tue Oct 30 18:27:00 2018
```

The yesterday tasks are still  pending there

```
atq     lists the user's pending jobs, unless the user is the superuser; in that case, every-
             body's jobs are listed;
```

However, yesterday has gone.

What's the reason `atq` demonstrate such a outdated list.

Comment: Did the command that was scheduled run successfully?  Was the system powered on at the scheduled time?

Comment: If the at daemon `atd` isn't running, your scheduled jobs won't be started.

Comment: could you please elaborate it,  I did not found `atd` $ atd
-bash: atd: command not found @UlrichSchwarz  on macos system

Comment: @Sawajiri: try `service atd status` or `ps -ef | grep atd`. As a system daemon, the binary live in `/usr/sbin/atd`, which is not usually in your executable search path, which is why you can't just start it.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz There is no `atd` on macOS (which is what the user is using according to most of their recent questions).